# Auto triggered update query in @Transactional | spring boot

Tags: java, sql, azure, spring-boot

I have two table (A,B)
Table A (have primary key e.g: id,activity_id)
Table B(have no primary key and column structure as activity_id,reasonCode )

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
method1{
  method 2();
  return;
}

method2{
insert into table B
}
```

Below are the query sequence

1. Hibernate: insert into Table B
2. Hibernate: update Table A
3. **Hibernate: update Table B**

After method1 execution completed the above query in Bold should not trigged as it's impact in response time.

Is this query in bold trigger because I don’t have in primary key in Table B ?

How to avoid the update query since I have already inserted the data in table B.

Comment: Question is not clear, can you make it more clear?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate ORM or jdbctemplate for insert? Until that is clear, it is very difficult to understand where the exact problem is.

Comment: We are using jdbctemplate

Answer (score 0):

I have added IDENTITY field as "id" in Table B. this resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The question is not clear. But just answer here if I guess it correctly.
You'll need to:

```
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
```

Before saving.